# Java asynchronous text input and output

Tags: java, asynchronous, io

i must say i am a beginner in Java.
I use Eclipse. I want to accomplish the following scenario and couldn't find how to do it:

While a java program runs it outputs text to the console, i also want to be able to input text and process it without blocking the output by waiting for input.

Assume this:

-Thread 1 outputs a number to the console every second

-Thread 2 listens for input

(The code is a mockup)

```
//**Thread 1:**

int incrementBy = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

    i = i + incrementBy;

    //Pause for 1 seconds
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("TEXT OUTPUT INTERUPTED");
    }
    //Print text
    System.out.println(i);
}



//**Thread 2:**
String myIncrement = System.console().readLine();

(Now process the input and change the incrementBy var in Thread 1)
```

Right now in my program i am using 1 thread for input and another one for output. But i can easily change the design.
All i could find was something about server and client, i would like to keep my code in one place-package. And i currently don't know how to make a GUI with a text box for output and one for input.

Can you recommend something please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED - it turns out I am VERY VERY new to JAVA.

It seems that java allows the user to input text while another thread outputs to the console.

This is the reason why i couldn't find anything in my searches for things like "java input and output to console asynchronous". I had a problem in my input code exactly where i was asking for input and because i knew from single threaded programs that the program halts until i enter the text and press enter i assumed that the error was thrown because the output thread was taking over the console and terminating the input thread.

Here is my code for those who search (Take it as a guide, might not work if compiled):

```js
//Main app
public class textInpuOutputManager {

  //here we create the two threads (objects that implement the runnable interface)
  static TextInputObject ti;
  static TextOutputObject to;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //we instantiate the objects
    ti = new TextInputObject();
    to = new TextOutputObject();
    //we call the start method to start the threads for input and output
    ti.start();
    to.start();
  }

}


//TextInputObject class
public class TextInputObject implements Runnable {

  //Method that gets called when the object is instantiated
  public TextInputObject() {
    System.out.println("Created TextInputObject");
  }

  //create a thread object and check if it's not already created
  static Thread thread;

  //This method gets called from the main
  public void start() {
    if (thread == null) {
      thread = new Thread(this);
      thread.start();
    }
  }

  //this method gets called by the thread.start(); from above
  @
  Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Text input thread created and now it runs");

    readTextFromConsole();
  }

  Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);

  //check for input all the time - THIS WILL NOT HALT THE PROGRAM
  public void readTextFromConsole() {
    System.out.println("Enter something:");
    String myinput = inputReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You Entered: " + myinput);
    readTextFromConsole();
  }

}


//TextOutputObject
public class TextOutputObject implements Runnable {

  //Method that gets called when the object is instantiated
  public TextOutputObject() {
    System.out.println("Created TextOutputObject");
  }

  static Thread thread;

  public void start() {
    if (thread == null) {
      thread = new Thread(this);
      thread.start();
    }
  }

  @
  Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Text output thread created and now it runs");

    //Make it output text every 4 seconds to test if you can input text while it's used for output
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      //Pause for 4 seconds
      try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("TEXT OUTPUT INTERUPTED");
      }
      //Print i to console
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

}
```

Also BIG thank you for all of you who took the time to respond

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what it is you want to do, but if you're new and you don't know how to make guis, I would try a JOptionPane

```
 String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("User input is returned as a string; use Integer.parseInt(input) to retrieve an integer from this method");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make two inner classes and implement Runnable in both of them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{

private Thread t1;
private Thread t2;    

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Test();
}

private class TOne implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        int incrementBy = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            i = i + incrementBy;

            //Pause for 1 seconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("TEXT OUTPUT INTERUPTED");
            }
            //Print text
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

private class TTwo implements Runnable{
    public void run(){//Code for Thread 2
        try{
            Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(scr.next());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public Test(){
    t1 = new Thread(new TOne());
    t1.run();
    t2 = new Thread(new TTwo());
    t2.run();
}
}
```

Not the most elegant way, and it doesn't work flawlessly. You'd have to tinker with the second Thread a little more. For information on how GUI etc. work you should check the Swing library. Googling it should work just fine.

Some important keywords for you wpuld be:
JFrame, JPanel, LayoutManager, JTextArea, JTextField, JButton, ActionListener, Inner Class

Comment: Thank you user3046986, your answer is almost the same as my approach, my problem was an exception thrown by bad coding exactly where i was asking for input and because of my past experience i jumped to the conclusion that the console doesn't allow it. Your answer made me take a better look at my code. Also thank you for the keywords, i'll sure check them out.